# Angular 9: Cannot read values in a nested object returned from API call [undefined]

Tags: angular, api, observable, angular9

I've only been developing with Angular 9 for 2 months, so forgive me if this is trivial :) 
Basically, I call an API which goes to the serverside and returns an object. This is a PUT request. I pass data along with the request and get a little something back.

API call from my service:

```
  verify(packGuid: string, userGuid: string, pinToVerify: string, device: string)
    :Observable<checkinStartedResponse> {
     
    return this.httpClient.put<checkinStartedResponse>(`package/CheckinStartedAction/${packGuid}/${userGuid}/${pinToVerify}/${device}`, null);
```

You see that I strong typed the expected Observable to be returned -> checkinStartedResponse
So, what is being returned is an object with some properties, where one of them is another custom object.

```
import { PINValidation } from './PINValidation';

export interface checkinStartedResponse {
  pinValidation: PINValidation,
  isActionComplete:boolean,
  pageToDisplay: string
}
```

PINValidation is:

```
export interface PINValidation {
  attemptsRemaining: number;
  canTryAgain: boolean;
  isPINValid: boolean;
  packageId: string;
}
```

Here is my component calling that verifyPIN method from my service, expecting the data I want back. Hovering on verifyPIN, I see it wants Observable<checkinStartedResponse> back. Great.

```
    //try to verify PIN
   this.service.verifyPIN(this.packGuid, this.user.userGuid, this.pinToVerify, this.device)
    .subscribe( (data) => {
      console.log(data.isActionComplete);
    
      this.pinValidationResponse = data.pinValidation;
      this.pinValidationResponse.isPINValid = data.pinValidation.isPINValid;
      this.checkinResponse.pinValidation.isPINValid = data.pinValidation.isPINValid;

      this.passVerficiation = this.pinValidationResponse.isPINValid;
    
    if (this.passVerficiation) {
        console.log("ya");
        this.PINverified.emit(true);
        this.closeModal();
    }
```

**The Concern**
Debugging and using Console.log, I can totally read the value of isActionComplete and pageToDisplay. **see image** But if I try to read values within the nested pinValidation object within my component, it's always undefined.

If I debug in the server code, I see the API call get processed. So, it does return the object I want, I just can't read it. My clientside class was created off of the serverside class. Again, I get data in the two properties isActionComplete and pageToDisplay, but I can't read values in this nested object. 

Sorry, my **first post**, I'm new at this :(
[debugging see values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pas1.png)

Small update: I can test api in Postman and the expected response in the right format returns.
I can also spit it out it JSON.

**THANK YOU!! <3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple issues here.

1. `isPINValid` != `isPinValid`. The properties in JS objects are case sensitive. The response from the API has the property `isPinValid`, but you're trying `isPINValid` which isnt' defined in the response.
2. You don't have to individually assign each property of the object. Assigning the object implies the properties are also assigned.

Try the following

```js
this.pinValidationResponse: checkinStartedResponse;      // <-- define the type here

this.service.verifyPIN(this.packGuid, this.user.userGuid, this.pinToVerify, this.device)
  .subscribe((data: checkinStartedResponse) => {         // <-- expect the type
    console.log(data.isActionComplete);

    this.pinValidationResponse = data.pinValidation;
    this.passVerficiation = data.pinValidation.isPinValid;    // <-- access `isPinValid` not `isPINValid`

    if (this.passVerficiation) {
      console.log("ya");
      this.PINverified.emit(true);
      this.closeModal();
    }
  });
```

Comment: So, you are the greatest! Honestly, in my spectacular newbdome, I didn't realize the case sensitivity had to be there, so you taught me something huge.  It's working now :)

So, I changed the property in PINValidationi to match the case in the response:
``` 
  isPinValid: boolean;
```
That worked, then I cleaned up my code.  :)